# Run jobs with SLURM on two nodes on IDLE status

Tags: nodes, slurm

I'm new with slurm and I have two nodes on IDLE status but my jobs run only on one of them, the master node (node01), while I do not understand why the second one (node02) doesn't run jobs.

I created a while loop for 500 jobs to submit

`while read f1 f2; do sbatch myscript.sh ${f1} ${f2}; done < list.txt`

On the header of the script "myscript.sh" I have

```
#SBATCH --job-name=test_jobs
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=3
#SBATCH --mem=1G
#SBATCH --time=00:03:00
#SBATCH --output=sslurm_%j.log
```

Looking the slurm.conf file

```
# Node
NodeName=node01 CPUs=80 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=20 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=515619
NodeName=node02 CPUs=80 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=20 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=515619
# Partition
PartitionName=base Nodes=node01,node02 Default=Yes MaxTime=7-00:00:00 Priority=1 State=U
```

node02 should read the script from node01 because I created an NFS shared folder where I keep the script. In the script are reported the path of the tools to use and those tools are only on node01 (some unde /usr/bin/ and other in a folder created from me). Should I also share the folders where are located the input files and tools?

What is wrong here? and also how can I print in the log files with which node ran each job?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By requesting `#SBATCH --nodes=2` in the submission script, you request that each job be allocated two nodes. I guess your program is multithreaded and cannot run on two nodes at the same time, so node02 is doing nothing in practice, but it is still allocated alongside node01 to each job.

So you should remove that line `#SBATCH --nodes=2`.

Furthermore, you need to make sure you enable node sharing among jobs as the node offer 80 CPUs but the jobs need 3. `SelectType` should be `select/cons_res` or `select/cons_tres`

> Should I also share the folders where are located the input files and tools?

Yes. Slurm does not take care of copying files for you, it assumes they are available on the compute nodes.

Comment: Hi damienfrancois, in the slurm.conf file I already have: SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU_Memory

Comment: I also deleted the "--nodes=2" and I can submit but only some of them run on the master node and the other die immidieatly. If I add --nodelist=node01,node02 , all run but only using the node01.

Comment: sorry, now I read the last part "Yes. Slurm does not take care of copying files for you, it assumes they are available on the compute nodes." ... it is logical, I will share also theme.